# Instagram additional permission review error

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I am trying to get additional permission in Instagram API but its shows this error as below.

[image]

Now it does not show any option for additional permission.

[image]

I need public_content for my app. How do I go about this ?

Comment: Please post code, not screenshots. Also the code that you use and causes the error.

Comment: @andrey its not code. Its a permission request. Check screenshot please